# How can I change a Microsoft Access form view from Single Form to Continous Forms at Runtime?

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access

I want to put a button in my form that changes its view with a button click.
I tried putting in this subroutine:

```
Pricate Sub SwitchView_Click()
    Me.DefaultView = 1
End Sub
```

But upon running it, I encountered an error that says

```
Run-time error '2136': To set this property, open the form or report in Design View.
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is unambiguous: this is a property that can only be set in Design view.

So you have to switch view, set the property, switch back.
I would put this into a standard module, not into the form module.

```
Private Sub SwitchView_Click()
    Call SwitchDefaultView(Me)
End Sub

' in standard module
Public Sub SwitchDefaultView(frm As Form)

    Dim sFrm As String

    ' Make sure the current record is (and can be) saved
    On Error Resume Next
    frm.Dirty = False
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox Err.Description: Exit Sub

    On Error GoTo 0
    sFrm = frm.Name
    ' Switch to Design view
    DoCmd.OpenForm sFrm, acDesign
    Forms(sFrm).DefaultView = 1     ' Continuous form
    ' DoCmd.Save acForm, sFrm         ' optional
    ' Switch back to Form view
    DoCmd.OpenForm sFrm, acNormal

End Sub
```

Although I wonder: usually a form is designed for either continuous or single form. I have a hard time imagining the use case for this switch.

Comment: I finally figured that there is no such way to change views from single form to continuous form directly. But you have provided a brilliant workaround.

Answer (score 4):

First issue is that you can not display a button on the Datasheet view, so you may have to use the Dbl_Click event.

In any regard, something like this :

```
Private Sub SwitchView_Click()

Select Case Me.CurrentView
     Case 1
          'Currently in form view
           DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDesignView
     Case 2
          'Currently in datasheet view
           DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdFormView
     Case Else
          'Must be design view (0) or some as yet undefined view
          'So do nothing.
End Select
```

Comment: The form was never in a datasheet view. I am asking how to go from a Single form( which CAN display a button ) to a Continuous Form.

Comment: Plus my form is not a sub form. I tried running your code and it gave me this error " Run-time error '2046': The command or action 'SubFormDatasheet' isn't available now."

Answer (score 1):

Test for DefaultView setting and change as appropriate.

```
Private Sub SwitchView_Click()
Me.Dirty = False
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDesignView
Select Case Forms!formname.DefaultView
     Case 0
        'Currently single view, change to continuous
        Forms!formname.DefaultView = 1
     Case 1
        'Currently continuous view, change to single
        Forms!formname.DefaultView = 0
     Case Else
        'do nothing.
End Select
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdFormView
End Sub
```

Or shorter code doesn't bother with testing since button is clickable only in Single or Continuous mode.

```
Private Sub SwitchView_Click()
Me.Dirty = False
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDesignView
Forms!formname.DefaultView = Abs(Forms!formname.DefaultView - 1)
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdFormView
End Sub
```

Examples use RunCommand to change view modes but could use OpenForm as well.

Closing form will trigger prompt asking if want to save changes. This can be overridden in Close command Save argument. However, if users utilize X close or right click menu this prompt will still trigger. Can disable those features in form design.

Answer (score 0):

To change the View of a SubForm to switch between Continuous and Datasheet View from a Main Form, create a button called "**cmdToggleView**" with the following On Click Event:

(Substitute the SubForm Name with your own Subform Name)

```
Private Sub cmdToggleView_Click()

    If Me.frmViewDetailedTransactionsSub.Form.CurrentView = 1 Then
        Me.frmViewDetailedTransactionsSub.SetFocus
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSubformDatasheetView
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Me.frmViewDetailedTransactionsSub.Form.CurrentView = 2 Then
        Me.frmViewDetailedTransactionsSub.SetFocus
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSubformFormView
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```